# server crashing because server is running a service that is using kernel space Linux

Tags: linux

Is there any way to disable a service that keeps restarting the server after the crash only to crash again? I assume I need to go into run level 1 but unsure of how to actually do the disabling in Debian at run level 1.
I can't use a snapshot or back up but really curious on how to disable the service before I crash again.

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Which service?  There are multiple ways to change boot behavior with systemd kernel command line arguments

Comment: this is just in theory but we could go with nginx